# key issues : aws EC2-instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing some login problem for accessing instance. While login to the server console (its a live server) it shows as Permission denied (publickey), Also am accessing with sudo also same issue persists. AWS instance, should reboot, no change while login issue persists.

Comment: hi, am using linux server,already changed the permission and again shows Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the permissions issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you got a public key when you set up the server and you saved it (.pem file), you first need to change permissions to it. If in Linux `cd`  to the directory holding the  `.pem` file, then do this:
`chmod 400 /path/to/your_public_key.pem` for only-read permission.
Then with your EC2 instance public DNS ( get it in AWS EC2 console when you click on your instance ID) which is similar to `ec2-x-xxx-xx.us-east-3.compute.amazonaws.com` ,you can `ssh`  into your server as follows. Assuming your user account name in the server is `ubuntu` like in most of the Linux based AMIs in AWS, do:

`ssh -i your_public_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-x-xxx-xx.us-east-3.compute.amazonaws.com` and if prompted for a password, provide it.

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#troubleshoot-unprotected-key) your key needs **correct permissions**:

> If you are connecting from MacOS or Linux, run the following command to fix this error, substituting the path for your private key file.

> chmod 0400 .ssh/my_private_key.pem